# How to add video to iOS app intro screen like Uber

Tags: ios, objective-c

Looking to add a video to my apps intro screen like the Uber app. I am sure there are others.

I found this which uses a gif and UIWebView, but not sure if this is the best solution. I definitely don't want to use images and stitch them together (would rather not have video if that is the preferred method).

https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2

Comment: Put video file into your app will make its size bigger. Animation gif or using CoreAnimation will be better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we add a video instead of launch image in an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765985/how-can-we-add-a-video-instead-of-launch-image-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: Launch image is different. I am talking about after the launch image. Like the signup/ signin screen like Uber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use in my app Letsplay, The answer from Aslam will work but uses MPmoviePlayerController which is depreciated as of IOS 9.0.
Also I set the video gravity so that your video will fill the entire frame which means no black borders.

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icebergs" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: videoPath];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil]];

AVPlayer* videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer* videoPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:videoPlayer];
[videoPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoPlayerLayer];
[videoPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[videoPlayer play];
```

If you don't want sound then remember to mute the player

```
[videoPlayer setMuted:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the code, but I it should work. It generally takes the path of the video file and adds it to the view controller. You may have to set the coordinates and size. Though I have used here video, GIF is more preferred.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    [self loadVideoInBackgroundOfView];

}


-(void)loadVideoInBackgroundOfView{
    MPMoviePlayerController*  videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self getTheVideoPath]];
    [videoPlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayer.view atIndex:0];
    [videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [videoPlayer play];

}

-(NSURL*)getTheVideoPath{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VideoFileName" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    return URL;
}
```